# VBA AutoFilter for checkmarked listbox items

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I know I can filter a range in Excel with VBA under use of `AutoFilter` e.g.:

```
Sub name()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$Y$74").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="String"
End Sub)
```

... that work's perfectly fine. However, I am struggling to make it a bit more sophisticated. Does anyone have an idea how the following example can be implemented in VBA?

What I would like to do is to filter for checkmarked items from a `List Box` with `Operator:=xlAnd` between each checkmarked list item.

Example: If I checkmark `String1` and `String2` in the following `List Box` the `AutoFilter` function should return all rows that contain `String1` and `String2`. In case of the table below, this would be row 2 and row 4.

[image]

```
| 1 | String1                   |
| 2 | String2, String1          |
| 3 | String2                   |
| 4 | String1, String2, String3 |
| 5 | String3                   |
| 6 | String1                   |
| 7 | String3, String1          |
```

Comment: I would add a hidden helper column that returns true if the terms are found in the column of interest, while false if not. you can then use the autofilter to hide rows returned as false. Tie that in with the Listbox change event and you should be able to get an autoupdating table.

Comment: @Jonas any reason why you have not assigned the bounty yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution which is inspired by Xabier's answer. It features two "scenarios".

1) Display rows in which the string in the cell under scrutinty contains either `String1` **or** `String2`

2) Display rows in which the string in the cell under scrutinty contains `String1` **and** `String2`

```
Sub AoP()

StartRow = 13
EndRow = 73
TargetColumn = 19 '(R)

LengthListBox = (ActiveSheet.ListBox1.ListCount - 1) ' Number of ListBox entries

ReDim TestXYZ(LengthListBox) As Integer 'Permanent list of checkmarked ListBox entries as ones and zeros
ReDim CheckList(LengthListBox) As String 'Permanent list of checkmarked ListBox entries as strings
ReDim Matches(LengthListBox) As Integer 'Temporary list of matches between search criteria and cell content

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Create arrays with information on the ListBox
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

For i = 0 To LengthListBox 'For 0 to length of ListBox
    If ActiveSheet.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then 'Loop
        TestXYZ(i) = 1 ' Checkmarked = 1
        CheckList(i) = ActiveSheet.ListBox1.List(i)
    Else
        TestXYZ(i) = 0 ' Not checkmarked = 0
    End If
Next i

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Hide rows that do not match a specific criteria
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'If OR is selected as an operator
If ActiveSheet.CheckBox_AoP_Or.Value = True Then ' If "Or" is selected as an operator
    For i = StartRow To EndRow 'For each row
        ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Hide all rows ifnot
        For j = 0 To LengthListBox 'For 0 to length of ListBox
            If Len(CheckList(j)) > 0 Then
                If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, TargetColumn).Value, CheckList(j), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'If the cell contains the checked ListBox string
                    ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Unhide the row
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
'If OR is NOT selected as an operate (behave like AND)
Else ' If "Or" is NOT selected as an operator
    For i = StartRow To EndRow 'For each row
        ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Hide all rows ifnot
        For k = 0 To LengthListBox 'Makes sure that the matches are set to zero
            Matches(k) = 0
        Next k
        For j = 0 To LengthListBox 'Parse through all list box entries
            If TestXYZ(j) = 1 Then ' If they have been checkmarked
                If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, TargetColumn).Value, CheckList(j), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' ... and if they are contained in the string
                    Matches(j) = 1 ' Contained = 1
                Else
                    Matches(j) = 0 ' Not contained = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(TestXYZ) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Matches) Then 'If all are contained (all are matched so the sum of 1 is equal)
            ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False '... then unhide
        End If
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested it, but in theory, this works with autofilter too:

```
Sub name()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$Y$74").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="*String1*", _
Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="*String2*"
End Sub)
```

If you can modify the `String1` and `String2` to include `*` either in the code or list box, I think this should work to find those scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. It does. But what if I have an array with `n`strings and not individual strings? ... autofilter whether a cell conatins all (`xlAnd`) srrings from an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple values to Filter by, what I would do is add them values to an Array and then use the values from the Array to filter the range, such as below:

```
Sub Autofiler_Array()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("String1", "String2", "String3")
'declare and assign values to Array

If ws.FilterMode Then ws.Range("$A$12:$Y$74").AutoFilter
'if Worksheet already is Filtered, then remove Autofilter
ws.Range("$A$12:$Y$74").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=myarray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
'Autofilter with Array Values on Column 22 of the applicable range
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

After reading your comments and updated question, I believe the following will achieve your desired results, instead of using the AutoFilter, the code below will loop through your rows, check if the cell contains all values from the Array, if not hiding them rows:

```
Sub Auto_Filter()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with
Dim arrWords  As Variant
arrWords = Array("String1", "String2")
'declare and assign values to Array
ws.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
'unhide all rows
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get last row with data in Column A

For i = 2 To LastRow
'loop through rows
    For Each aWord In arrWords 'loop through Array values
        If Not InStr(ws.Cells(i, 22).Value, aWord) > 0 Then
            ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            'if values from Array not found in cell, then hide row
        End If
    Next
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer goes into the right direction but does not fully work yet. Only exact matches are filtered and only if the string in the cells starts with an array item.

Comment: @Jonas, I've now updated my answer to reflect your comments, hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Xabier! I think it's not exactly what I asked for since scenarios where I wuld like to pick several words from an array at the same time is not considered. However, the suggestion to use `hide` did point me in the right direction. I will copy my code below.

Answer (score 1):

**AutoFilter a range using an Array**

**Requirement:** Filter a range in order to show all the rows that contain all the items in an array.
i.e. for the Array = (“String1”, “String2”, “String3”, “String4”, “String5” )
The AutoFilter should include all the rows that contain “String1”, “String2”, “String3”, “String4” and “String5” in any position.
This should the equivalent to being able to perform something like this as a custom AutoFlter:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=sCriteria1, Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:=sCriteria2, Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria3:=sCriteria3, Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria4:=sCriteria4, Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria5:=sCriteria5, Operator:=xlAnd, _
    …, _
    CriteriaN:=sCriteriaN
```

**Solution:** This proposed solution:
1.  Process the array values (each two) in order to generate an array of filtered ranges
2.  Obtains the intersection of filtered ranges array
3.  Hides all the rows in the target range and unhides all the rows in the intersection range
4.  Creates an array with all the values in step 4
5.  Filters the target range applying the array generated in step 4

The advantages of this procedure are:
   It does not loop through each of the rows of the target range.
   Returns an AutoFilter, so additional filters can be applied to other fields without losing the Array AutoFilter.

**Procedure:**

*Function **Range_ƒFilter_ByArray_Contains**(aCriteria As Variant, rTrg As Range, sMsg As String) As Boolean*
Returns as boolean
Filters a Target range (rTrg) applying all the values in the Criteria array (aCriteria), returning also a message (sMsg) in case of Error.

```
Function Range_ƒFilter_ByArray_Contains(aCriteria As Variant, _
    rTrg As Range, sMsg As String) As Boolean
Dim blAfByAry As Boolean
Dim arAFs() As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim bDim As Byte
Dim sCriteria1 As String, sCriteria2 As String
Dim rAFs As Range, aAFcontains As Variant
Dim b As Byte

    Rem Validate Input
    If (rTrg Is Nothing) Then sMsg = "Target range is invalid": GoTo Exit_Err
    If Not (IsArray(aCriteria)) Then sMsg = "aCriteria is not an array": GoTo Exit_Err
    On Error Resume Next
    aCriteria = WorksheetFunction.Index(aCriteria, 0, 0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo Exit_Err
    bDim = UBound(aCriteria, 2)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then sMsg = "aCriteria is not a single dimension array": GoTo Exit_Err
    On Error GoTo Exit_Err

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With rTrg

        Rem Clear AutoFilter
        With .Worksheet
            On Error Resume Next
            If Not .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        Rem Dimensioning AutoFilters Range Array
        bDim = UBound(aCriteria)
        blAfByAry = bDim > 2
        If blAfByAry Then
            If WorksheetFunction.IsOdd(bDim) Then bDim = 1 + bDim
            bDim = (bDim / 2)
            ReDim Preserve arAFs(1 To bDim)
        End If

        For b = 1 To UBound(aCriteria) Step 2

            Rem Apply AutoFilter Criterias (2 each time)
            sCriteria1 = aCriteria(b)
            Select Case b
            Case UBound(aCriteria)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sCriteria1
            Case Else
                sCriteria2 = aCriteria(1 + b)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sCriteria1, _
                    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=sCriteria2
            End Select

            Rem Set AutoFilter Range Item
            If blAfByAry Then Set arAFs((1 + b) / 2) = rTrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Next: End With

    If blAfByAry Then

        Rem Set AutoFilters Range
        Set rAFs = arAFs(1)
        For b = 2 To UBound(arAFs)
            Set rAFs = Application.Intersect(rAFs, arAFs(b))
        Next

        With rTrg

            Rem Clear AutoFilter
            rTrg.AutoFilter

            Rem Apply AutoFilters Range
            .EntireRow.Hidden = True
            rAFs.EntireRow.Hidden = False

            With ThisWorkbook

                Rem Set AutoFilter Array Criteria
                Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
                With ws
                    rAFs.Copy
                    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial
                    aAFcontains = .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value2
                    aAFcontains = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aAFcontains)
                    ws.Delete

            End With: End With

            Rem Apply AutoFilter Array Criteria
            rTrg.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:=aAFcontains, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    End With: End If

    Range_ƒFilter_ByArray_Contains = True

Exit_Err:

    With Err
        If .Number <> 0 Then sMsg = "Error: " & .Number & vbLf & vbTab & .Description
    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    End Function
```

The procedure should be used like this:

```
Set rTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(kWsh).Range(kRng)
If Not (Range_ƒFilter_ByArray_Contains(aCriteria, rTrg, sMsg)) Then
    MsgBox sMsg, vbCritical, "Range_ƒFilter_ByArray_Contains"
End If
```

***Note:*** This solution only handles the `xlAnd` operator in line with the original OP's question, nevertheless it can be easily modified to include work also with the `xlOr` operator.